# Is there a way to connect my local spark instance to Azure Blob storage?

Tags: azure

Is there a way to connect my local spark instance to Azure Blob storage ? The internet has only ways of connecting Azure Databricks to BLOB storage but nothing about accessing data via my local instance.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to add further detail. For example: what do you mean by "local instance" - native spark? Also, please include what you've tried, and where you're stuck.

Comment: can you please share more details on what you are trying to achieve